# Longest Palindromic Substring

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x

I wrote the following code for [this problem.](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1297) The problem is to find the longest palindromic substring.
I think it is correct and is working correctly for all the test cases I entered myself. Now, the code is producing a Time Limit Exceeded Error. I know that there exists Manacher's Algorithm which does it in linear time but I thought of the following solution myself and wanted to implement it. I believe that it's time complexity is less as compared to \$\mathcal{O}(n^3)\$ and other \$\mathcal{O}(n^3)\$ solutions have been accepted which makes me feel that I am missing something important.

```
string = input()

longest = 0
position = 0
string = string.replace('', '^')
length = len(string)

##print(string)

for index, letter in enumerate(string):
##    print()
##    print('Index:', index, 'Letter:', letter)

    stretch = 1

    while string[index-stretch:index+stretch+1] == string[index-stretch:index+stretch+1][::-1]\
          and index - stretch >= 0 and index + stretch < length:
##        print('Matching Strings:', string[index-stretch:index+stretch+1], string[index-stretch:index+stretch+1][::-1], 'Stretch:', stretch)
        stretch += 1

##    print('Not Matched:', string[index-stretch:index+stretch+1], string[index-stretch:index+stretch+1][::-1], 'Stretch:', stretch)

    stretch -= 1

    if stretch > longest:
##        print('Highest Till Now')
        longest = stretch
        position = index - stretch


##print(position, longest)

print(string[position:position+(2*longest+1)].replace('^', ''))
```

`stretch` is the extension of the palindrome on either side of its center. `longest` stores the length of the longest substring found till then. `position` stores the index of the starting letter of `longest`. Please ask if you have any doubts.

What I want to know is that am I missing something which is causing the program to lose its efficiency? How can I overcome it? Can you suggest some improvements to the algorithm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I'll highlight areas I felt you should change.

1. Make a function.
2. Don't litter the program with blackbox debugging 'comments'.
3. Don't use `enumerate` if you don't need both `index` *and* `letter`.
4. It's easier to read one slice rather than two.
5. You could change your while loop to a for loop, this reduces the amount of statements in the if.

Most of these are pretty simple, and are mostly due to your debugging.
I'll elaborate on 5 as it's the only one that I should need to explain.

If we rearrange both \$\text{index} - \text{stretch} >= 0\$ and \$\text{index} + \text{stretch} < \text{length}\$ to get stretch.
This gets \$\text{index} >= \text{stretch}\$ and \$\text{length} - \text{index} > \text{stretch}\$.
As we know the input are integers we can get both to use the same sign, `>`.
With \$\text{index} + 1 > \text{stretch}\$.
If we merge them both together we get: \$\text{min}(\text{index} + 1, \text{length} - \text{index}) > \text{stretch}\$.

This basically means you can use the following range:

```
for stretch in range(1, min(index + 1, length - index)):
```

You should note, it won't go above the largest possible stretch and so you should only do `stretch -= 1` if you break from the loop.

All of this together should get you:

```
def get_longest_palendrome(string):
    string = string.replace('', '^')
    longest = 0
    position = 0
    length = len(string)
    for index in range(length):
        stretch = 0
        for stretch in range(1, min(index + 1, length - index)):
            text = string[index - stretch:index + stretch + 1]
            if text != text[::-1]:
                stretch -= 1
                break
        if stretch > longest:
            longest = stretch
            position = index
    position -= longest
    return string[position:position + (2*longest + 1)].replace('^', '')
```

---

The second I looked at `string = string.replace('', '^')` I thought this can't be an \$O(n^3)\$ algorithm.
I don't know the actual complexity, but you instantly change the length of string to \$2n + 1\$.
This means your function is more \$O((2n)^3)\$ or \$O(8n^3)\$

I know you normally ignore the coefficient but I think it's quite important to highlight the pitfall on doubling the size of the input.